# How to resolve Generics in macros?

Tags: crystal-lang

```
macro m(type)
  {% puts type.resolve %}
end

module Foo
  class Bar
  end

  class Baz
    m(Array(Bar))
  end
end

# in temp4.cr:10: undefined macro method 'Generic#resolve'
# 
#     m(Array(Bar))
```

I need to resolve `Array(Bar)` so it prints type with full paths (`Array(Foo::Bar)`). Is there a convenient way of doing so **regardless of the type complexity** (e.g. `Array(Bar, Array(SomeOtherType) | Int32)`)?

Comment: There's no way to do it right now, please open a feature request (I can't guarantee it will get implemented, though, mostly because of time, effort and priorities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by this PR: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/6617. Thanks Ary!